# Create excel in Resteasy

Tags: java, apache-poi, resteasy

I would like to create/return an excel file from my RestEasy webservice but am having some trouble getting it to work. When i run the code below (pseudo code) I get the following error:

> org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not
>   find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type:
>   java.io.FileOutputStream of media type: application/vnd.ms-excel

Here is some code

```
@POST
@Path("/exportMyData")
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
public Response getMyData(@FormParam("id") String id) {
    HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    ResponseBuilder response = null;
    try{
        List<Alert> alertList= service.getAlerts(id);


        HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

        HSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);
        rowhead.createCell((int) 0).setCellValue("ID");
        rowhead.createCell((int) 1).setCellValue("Name");
        rowhead.createCell((int) 2).setCellValue("Age");


        for(Alert alert : alertList){
            HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)1);
            row.createCell((int) 0).setCellValue(alert.getId());
            row.createCell((int) 1).setCellValue(alert.getName());
            row.createCell((int) 2).setCellValue(alert.getAge());
        }


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("mystream.xls");
        hwb.write(fos);
        response = Response.ok(fos);            
        response.header("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=export.xls");
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    return response.build();
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance
/Eric

Comment: Why are you writing the excel spreadsheet to a temporary file? Why not just pass POI the response output and have it sent straight to the client?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, i tryed writing the poi to the output stream with the following code

  ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
  hwb.write(os);
  os.close();

But no success, get no error or file back

Answer (score 8):

I've found that if you do the following, it'll work:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
hwb.write(baos);
response = Response.ok(baos.toByteArray());
response.header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.xls");
```

Comment: I think it does not support xlsx? I get message while opening xlsx file that file may be corrupted.

Comment: Oh, I was stupid. Was using HSSF* to create xlsx instead of XSSF* library! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement of returning Excel does not require RestEasy. You can do this using plain old servlets.

RestEasy is for implementing REST services that return XML, JSON or plain text. @Produces does not support "application/vnd.ms-excel".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the custom mediaType using the MessageBodyWriter/MessageBodyReader interface.  Please refer to this ([How to handle/create new content-type/MediaType in JAX-RS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480830/how-to-handle-create-new-content-type-mediatype-in-jax-rs)).