# How to handle/create new content-type/MediaType in JAX-RS?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I am researching on Jersey and RESTEasy. Media-type negotiation for XML and JSON works fine, and I am able to consume and produce both of them. However, I am being asked to produce and consume a response for a new content-type. For instance, BSON, or a self customized content-type. I googled online but could not find much information in it. Is there anyway, I could still use the @Produces and @Consumes annotation in JAX-RS for the new content-type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can use `@Produces` and `@Consumes` with custom media types.  In order to use the custom media type when marshalling and unmarshalling content you need to create `MessageBodyWriter` and `MessageBodyReader` implementations to handle the media type.

**Here is how to implement a custom media type:**

1. Annotate your resource methods with `@Consumes({"application/mycustomtype})` and `@Produces({"application/mycustomtype})` as required.
2. Implement custom `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` implementations to support your custom media type.
3. Annotate your `MessageBodyReader` with `@Provider` and `@Consumes({"application/mycustomtype})`
4. Annotate your `MessageBodyWriter` with `@Provider` and
   `@Produces({"application/mycustomtype})`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hints. Looked into these classes on Google and found these links useful too.
[messagebodywriter](http://alex.vanboxel.be/2010/11/09/evolve-with-messagebodywriter/), 
[messagebodywriter2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741853/how-to-write-an-xml-messagebodywriter-provider-with-jersey), and 
[ibm's example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jaxrs/)
Thank you very much.